# Obtain pre-installed W8 key, and install W8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, installation, product-key

I have a Lenovo Z580, which has a pre-installed copy of Windows 8.

I want to install only Ubuntu & Windows 7 on it, so I want to format the whole hard-drive.
However, I'd like to retain the product key, so that I can re-install Windows 8 in the future.

Now, how do I obtain the product key? Also, if I want to re-install Windows 8, how do I get a legitimate ISO or CD, without paying any extra money?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OEM keys for windows 8 are generally built into the bios and Windows 8 should auto-activate when its reinstalled.

As for install media, your best bet would be having a read pm the Lenovo community website.

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Windows-8/Buyer-Beware-Don-t-format-your-windows-8-disk/td-p/922487

Comment: Since they're built into the BIOS, then formatting the hard drive will not affect them, right?
And, this recovery drive that I create is equivalent to an install disc ( as in previous versions of Windows ), right?

Comment: Correct on both counts, a recovery disk is generally a better option as they usually contain drivers for the device without having to rely on standard Windows 8 drivers.